# what does an input event on a component do in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

The following piece of code is taken from the Vue documentation:

```
<ChildComponent v-model="pageTitle" />

<!-- would be shorthand for: -->

<ChildComponent :value="pageTitle" @input="pageTitle = $event" />
```

There is an input event on a component. I understand what an input event does on an input. But what does the input event do on a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` is short for `v-on` directive which is used to listen to DOM events emitted/triggered from a specific element. Now most of the `native elements` will interact with the outside world by emitting their own corresponding events by default. For instance, `div` element triggers `click` event, `input` element triggers `input`, `change`, `focus` and other helpful events.

Unlike `native elements`, there is absolutely no events triggered BY DEFAULT in a custom component. Therefore, you can only listen to events that are emitted from within the component. Those are `custom events`, so you can rest assure that none of these event setups below will work unless inside each component emits their own `click`, `input`, `focus` event respectively:

```
<ComponentA @click="onClickComponentA" />
<ComponentB @input="onInputComponentB" />
<ComponentC @focus="onFocusComponentC" />
```

In your case, `ChildComponent` is clearly not a native element so inside this component, it must somewhere emit `input` event.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about `Custom events`, just read [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

Example:

```
Vue.component('custom-input', {
  props: ['value'],
  template: `
    <input
      v-bind:value="value"
      v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
    >
  
})
```

then you can use `custom-input` like this:

```
 <custom-input :value="pageTitle" @input="pageTitle = $event" />
```

where `$event` is a native event of the input